# Python: Multiprocessing with pool.map while main is still working

Tags: python, multiple-processes, process-pool

I am a few days into learning python, and would like to understand this.
I am doing a file explorer, and want to speed up thumbnail creation.
Watched a bunch of tutorials about multiprocessing, but none show hot to continue main(), while processes are running.
I need results in order.

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import image


folder='G:\+++CODING+++\\test3\\'


def process_file(filepath):
    return image.convert_to_bytes(filepath, resize=(100, 100))


def create_filepaths(folder):
    filepaths = []
    for file in os.scandir(folder):
        filepaths.append(os.path.join(folder, file))
    return filepaths


def main():
    def process1():
        print('process1 start')
        pool = Pool()
        return pool.map(process_file, create_filepaths(folder), chunksize=1)

    process1()
    while True:
        # do stuff


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have tried something like following, to combine with multiprocessing, but I cannot call process1 in the MainGuiLoop, and do my mainlogic there of course, since the loop is a thread only. I could do simple GuiUpdates only.
This question is only for understanding and learning, my final implementation has to be different.

```
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import image
from time import sleep, perf_counter
import threading


start_time = perf_counter()
folder='G:\+++CODING+++\\test3\\'


def process_file(filepath):
    return image.convert_to_bytes(filepath, resize=(100, 100))


def create_filepaths(folder):
    filepaths = []
    for file in os.scandir(folder):
        filepaths.append(os.path.join(folder, file))
    return filepaths


def main():
    def process1():
        print('process1 start')
        pool = Pool()
        return pool.map(process_file, create_filepaths(folder), chunksize=1)

    def thread_create():
        return threading.Thread(target=MainGuiLoop)

    def MainGuiLoop():
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("-")

    thread1 = thread_create()
    thread1.start()
    result1= process1()
    result2= process1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Bonus Question: As I understand .map is not accessible until it is finished. In fact I need it to update the thumbnails from time to time, so I have to use .map_async() Which solves the dead main(), but gives unordered results. But I could create my list with an id, and sort the results in chunks, that I want to draw on screen. Is that the right approach?

Comment: I guess I don't follow your goal. Is your goal to convert images to bytes from an array of image filepaths in a multiprocessed fashion? I got lost at `MainGuiLoop`.

Comment: My question was just general, how to use main() if you use .map.
In reality I just want to have the thumbnails in a list, that I want to periodically update to the screen as they are coming in.
I have realized this with threads,(not in example) till now, works perfectly.
But the real performance boost would be multiprocesses.
I am aware that .map is not callable until it is finished. So I will implement .map_async() with a unique id to sort it in chunks while they are coming in, and draw on screen.
But this will be a different question, if I don't manage alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation suggests that a [Process Pool Executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) is what you're looking for. Code below from the link. As for the unordered results, try passing in a sorted list.

```
import concurrent.futures
import math

PRIMES = [
    112272535095293,
    112582705942171,
    112272535095293,
    115280095190773,
    115797848077099,
    1099726899285419]

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for number, prime in zip(PRIMES, executor.map(is_prime, PRIMES)):
            print('%d is prime: %s' % (number, prime))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So, for your code:

```
import os
import concurrent.futures
import image

FOLDER = 'G:\+++CODING+++\\test3\\'

def process_file(filepath):
    return image.convert_to_bytes(filepath, resize=(100, 100))

def create_filepaths(folder):
    return sorted([os.path.join(folder, f) for f in os.scandir(folder)])

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        filepaths = create_filepaths(FOLDER)
        executor.map(process_file, filepaths) 
        while True:
            # do stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thx optimus. The docum. is still a bit chinese, but reading it in hindsight, it seems that it is what I need. I combined both your answers and added in ` while True:/for image in zip(result):/print(image)` I was surprised that I could access it while it is created.!! I thought I needed to do  .map_async(). Not sure what your sorted does, since filepaths are always sorted.??
I basically need the same order that the create_filepaths functions feeds, or basically the same order the `executor.map(process_file, filepaths)` FILEPATHS are in.
create_filepaths is only a dummy function.

Comment: Wow it is so much faster, than serial. Actually I realised, that you cannot access them, while they are created, it was just so fast, that I thought it can't be finished yet.
Well the question is answered, since the while loop is continuing, as long as you don't try to read the result with `for image in zip(result)´ after ...adding also `results= executor.map(process_file, filepaths)`
But I have a feeling this is somehow possible, to read a few, before everything is finished. I mean they are called futures. Not sure though...need sleep first.

Comment: btw I implemented it perfectly..all working.
If you want to use results as they are coming in, submit instead of map was the solution.
I can even cancel the creation, in case the user changes folder before thumbnails are finished.